# LINQ double join statement

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have table called Workbook which has 1-to-many relationship with table "Revisorsberetning" which was many-to-1 relationship with Project.
So:
Workbook --> Revisorsberetning --> Project

I just want to get a list of projects that is related to workbook given WorkbookId

I tried to convert the following SQL (SQL works) to LINQ but with no luck:

```
select Project.PROJECT_NAME
from Project
inner join dbo.Revisorsberetning
on dbo.Revisorsberetning.Project_ProjectId = dbo.Project.ProjectId
inner join dbo.Workbook
on dbo.Workbook.WorkbookId = 2
```

this is the LINQ (LinqPAD, thats why you see projectS and theres not dbcontext) query that doesnt seem to work properly:

```
var sss = from u in Projects
join uc in Revisorsberetnings on u.ProjectId equals uc.Project.ProjectId
join c in Workbooks on uc.Workbook.WorkbookId  equals c.WorkbookId
where c.WorkbookId == 2
select u.PROJECT_NAME;
```

Comment: if you mean that returns another value, try `select new {u.PROJECT_NAME, u.ProjectId };`

Comment: also in sql `dbo.Workbook.WorkbookId = 2` in your linq `c.WorkbookId == 1`

Comment: @Grundy that was just a typo and is not relative to the issue im having

Comment: @RedHotScalability Why didn't you write `on c.WorkbookId == 2` in your LIQN query to match your SQL query? Your SQL does not link `Workbook` to any other table, just grabbing the row with the id of 2.

Comment: @Grundy all the typos have been removed, they were not related to the issue. SQL query returns 4 elements, LINQ query returns two elements. so something is wrong with the query itself and not the representation of the results (SELECT)

Comment: you can try [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you may be onto something. I am total new at LINQ, I just tried to convert it line for line.

Comment: @AD.Net removing 2nd join and adjusting the where statement to  where uc.Workbook.WorkbookId == 2 did not work

Answer (score 0):

try this variant

```
var sss = from u in Projects
          join uc in Revisorsberetnings on u.ProjectId equals uc.Project.ProjectId
          from c in Workbooks
          where c.WorkbookId == 2
          select u.PROJECT_NAME;
```